# How can I make two materials blend?

Tags: materials

How can I two materials which are assigned to one model make blend? I have made a forest with different types of trees and I need the to have different leaves (as a texture) on it depending on under which tree it is. I tried texture painting it, but I would need resolution over 8000 x 8000 px and my computer can't handle that. this is what I could do so far:
[image: this is what I could do so far]

I need to get rid of these lines, so that it looks like real ground and not like bunch of pictures of fallen leafs.
[image: this is what I could do so far]

some of the trees are oaks, some are maples and some are beeches. I have texture of dead leafs for all those trees and I want it to fit the trees - under maple dead maple leafs and so on. On the screenshot above, the edge of the plane is gravel, orange is dead maple leafs, light brown is dead oak leafs and the other orange is dead beech leafs. I want it to blend, so that there would not be any visible seams. I am also limited on number of faces - maximum is 50 000 - so I can't make leafs as objects lay on the ground (I should have mentioned this earlier)

Comment: Please add images of the trees so people can understand you question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be specific. You can use nodes.
[image]

In the image you can see how I set it up. You set one material for whole ground and make it use nodes. Inside of nodes you mix between 2 materials using stencil texture. You can draw stencil texture in texture paint node. You may consider using seperate UV map for stencil.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a particle system to each type of trees you have in the scene  and create leave particles (perhaps a invsible plane parented to the trunk).

It looks like that you have a hilly terrain, in this case you could make the terrain a collision object and let the partices fall down. Note that would require to set physics from No back to Newton.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: that is basicaly, how I have done the leafs on the trees, but I have got about 30 trees and limit of 50 000 faces, so I can't make 2000 for each tree, just to make ground.

Comment: Couldn't you then cascade some mix shaders and control them by a procedural texture like musgrave or vornoi?